# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' | Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("demo.png")

New_img=img.thumbnail((90,90), Image.ANTIALIAS)

New_img.save("deTT.png")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sahejmundi/Desktop/projects/LiveProjects/XML_project/Task_4/img_re.py", line 15, in

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Provide code please.

Comment: code added in triple quotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your input Luke, it was my first question so it might have seemed vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thumbnail()` method reduces the size of the image passed to it *"in situ"* rather than returning a new, reduced image. So you actually need:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("demo.png")

# Reduce to thumbnail in place
img.thumbnail((90,90), Image.ANTIALIAS)

img.save("deTT.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very vague, but hope this helps

There seams to be an error when you defines your New_img function. If you can check the docs again and try to fix it

### Most likely, you missed a parenthesis somewhere ()

Something like this should work

```py
my_size = (90, 90)
image.thumbnail(my_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(path_to_image, 'image/png', optimize=True)
```